# Automatic URL redirects to Azure AD B2C application

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Under Azure AD B2C sign up custom policy When user completes sign-up process. After signup process user should automatically redirect to application.  Is this possible by any way.

Answer (score 0):

The sign up and sign in processes are different so I don't think you can do that at the same time. You can, however, redirect the user wherever you want. You can simply code in logic so that when the user hits "submit" he/she is redirected to the application page. You can set the reply url to return the user to the application. Then, after the user signs in, you use:

```
If (User.IsAuthenticated)
```

And direct the user wherever you want.